# Display unecessary rows in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on displaying a table of access that a user can have for reference.

I have a table like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
id  | header | module | submodule | add | edit | view | delete
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | users  | client |           | Y   | Y    | Y    | Y
 2  | users  | client | Active    | Y   | Y    | Y    | Y
 3  | users  | client | Inactive  | Y   | Y    | Y    | 
 4  | users  | client | Pending   | Y   | Y    |      |
```

The output I'm looking for is this

```
Header | Module | Submodule | Add | Edit | View | Delete
users  |        |           |     |      |      |
       | client |           | Y   | Y    | Y    | Y
       | client | Active    | Y   | Y    | Y    | Y
       | client | Inactive  | Y   | Y    | Y    | 
       | client | Pending   | Y   | Y    |      |
```

But the output I'm getting is this

```
Header | Module | Submodule | Add | Edit | View | Delete
users  |        |           |     |      |      |
       | client |           | Y   | Y    | Y    | Y
       | client | Active    | Y   | Y    | Y    | Y
       | client |           | Y   | Y    | Y    |
       | client | Inactive  | Y   | Y    | Y    |
       | client |           | Y   | Y    |      |
       | client | Pending   | Y   | Y    |      |
```

How do I remove the unnecessary fields?

Here is my current code on the controller

```
public function create() {
    $userGrid = DB::table('user_permissions_grid')
                   ->where('status', 'active')
                   ->orderBy('header', 'asc')
                   ->orderBy('module', 'asc')
                   ->orderBy('submodule', 'asc')
                   ->get();
}
```

Then on the view

```
<table class="table">
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Module/th>
    <th>Submodule</th>
    <th>Add</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>View</th>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($userGrid as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->header }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $row->module }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $row->add }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->edit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->view }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->delete }}</td>
        </tr>
        @if($row->submodule)
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $row->submodule }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->add }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->edit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->view }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->delete }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I display it to the desired output that I've posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it is displaying precisely what you have coded!

You are at first displaying a row with only the header on, then displaying a row with the module and permissions, before then seeing if the module has a sub-module and if so, printing the same row again, this time missing the module and only displaying the sub-module.

Therefore if a line has a module and a sub-module, you will get two corresponding rows.

I think the code should be like:

```
    @if($row->submodule)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $row->module }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->submodule }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->add }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->edit }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->view }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->delete }}</td>
    </tr>
    @else
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $row->module }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $row->add }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->edit }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->view }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->delete }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endif
```